# How to use javascript to check if input contains special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How do you use javascript to check if an input value on keyup contains any special characters? Below is the attempt using regex

```
function validatePassword(inputValidator) {
    let specialCharValidator = inputValidator.match(/[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]/g);
    if (specialCharValidator == null) {
        console.log("null");
    } else {
        console.log(specialCharValidator)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function validatePassword(value) {
    return (/[!@#\$%\^\&*\(\)\/\\+=._-]/g).test(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var format = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/;
if(format.test(string)){
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Works, but the approach in [ardean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311052/how-to-use-javascript-to-check-if-input-contains-special-characters/62311140#62311140)'s answer is much more concise.